# Adding a conditional filter clause

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, conditional-operator

This is my dataframe and filters:

```py
df = spark.range(3)

filter1 = (F.col('id') == 1)
filter2 = (F.col('id') == 2)
flag = False
```

I want to make `filter2` dependent on `flag`. When `flag = True`, I want `filter2` to take effect and not to take effect when `flag = False`.

I know I can do

```py
filt = filter1
if flag:
    filt = filt | filter2
df = df.filter(filt)
```

I wonder if this would be possible in one line, for example utilizing conditional expressions/ ternary operators, etc.

This did not work:

```
df = df.filter(filter1 | filter2 if flag else False)
```

Desired result when `flag = False`:

```
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  1|
+---+
```

Desired result when `flag = True`:

```
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  1|
|  2|
+---+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `filter2` with a bitwise `&` condition on the `flag` . This will only return True when both the `filter2` and `flag` returns True else False. Use this with filter1 with an or condition.

```
output = df.filter(filter1 |(filter2 & F.lit(flag)))
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried to nest it inside a `when-otherwise` block , surprisingly it works in a way -

**Data Preparation**

```
sparkDF = sql.range(3)

sparkDF.show()
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  0|
|  1|
|  2|
+---+
```

**True Flag - Filter - When - Otherwise**

```
filter1 = (F.col('id') == 1)
filter2 = (F.col('id') == 2)
flag = True

sparkDF.filter(F.when(F.lit(flag),filter1).otherwise(filter2)).show()
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  1|
+---+
```

**False Flag - Filter - When - Otherwise**

```
filter1 = (F.col('id') == 1)
filter2 = (F.col('id') == 2)
flag = False

sparkDF.filter(F.when(F.lit(flag),filter1).otherwise(filter2)).show()
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  2|
+---+
```

However I do suspect , if the filter conditions will add multiple columns to filter upon this would break.

Maybe you can have a further nested `when-when-*-otherwise` to work in that case.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. Bouncing from where you left it I did it using `when-otherwise`.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked. But I am still open for suggestions employing python's conditional expressions/ ternary operators. Employing them, conditions would not be repeated - as can be seen, now `filter1` is repeated two times.

```
df = df.filter(F.when(F.lit(flag), filter1 | filter2).otherwise(filter1))
```